Error while running mvn clean install: Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.7.4:scr (generate-scr-descriptor)
I receive the following error when trying to run command mvn clean install:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.7.4:scr (generate-scr-descriptor) on project companyname-bundle: Execution generate-scr-descriptor of goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.7.4:scr failed: org.apache.felix.scrplugin.tags.annotation.AnnotationTagProvider is not an ImageIO SPI class -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :companyname-bundle

I have maven version 3.5.4 and Java 11.
Code in my bundle pom.xml file:
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-scr-descriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>scr</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>

Code in my main pom.xml file:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
</plugin>

I have tried varying the versions of java with java version 1.8 and maven using maven version 3.6.3 and get an error regarding surefire-plugin
Tried changing version of scr-plugin to be 1.22.0 from 1.7.4, but i get this error:
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.22.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:jar:1.22.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:pom:1.22.0 from/to barclays (https://nexus.barcapint.com/nexus/content/groups/barclays/): Connection reset -> [Help 1]


This: lays/): Connection reset looks like network error or proxy/firewall issue...... also use more recent versions of the plugin as well as your Maven version please upgrade...

Fixed this issue by having the right Java and Maven versions. Mvn: 3.5.4, Java 1.8
